# Will I be able to level up enough to unlock all the stats?

Tags: adventure-time-hikwysog

So far, leveling up has been simple. I open a chest, I get a star, I level up a stat.

I'm a little worried thoug.  I've only been able to find 2 stars per Kingdom thus far. After having just finished the Candy Kingdom, I'm a little worried that I won't be able to collect enough stars to level up completely before going on to New Game+.

**Are there enough stars to allow for maxed out stats?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need 12 stars to level all your stats, and there are 12 stars in the game! So you should happily be able to max out all the things.

In case you need help finding them, here are their locations (and [this guide](http://www.gamefaqs.com/ds/664761-adventure-time-hey-ice-king-whyd-you-steal-our/faqs/65322) can help you further):

> - Grass Lands - Northeast path
> - Tree Dungeon - Near the room with the Dungeon Key. Requires Beauteous
>                     Wings or Ear Shield.
> - Tomb Dungeon - In the lower right room, in the area that requires using
>                     Down Thrust to open the path forward.
> - Nut Path - Near the middle of the path. Requires Fist Smash.
> - Grass Lands - Beyond the stone barrier to the southwest, in a cave
>                     hidden by four bushes. Requires the Heavy and Fist Smash
>                     abilities, and Stars of Frozen Rain loot.
> - Door Lord Path - Behind a gate triggered by a Down Thrust stone switch.
> - Rock Dungeon - Near the beginning of the dungeon. Requires Umbrella.
> - Red Rock Pass - In a cave on the southwestern island. Requires Ship.
> - Red Rock Pass - In a cave on the island in the center of the world.
>                     Requires Ship.
> - Ice Kingdom - In the Ice-O-Pede's Lair.
> - Ice Kingdom - Path to Ice Kingdom. Break the ice blocks in the middle of
>                     the path. Requires the Glowing Sword.
> - Ice Kingdom - In the Ice King's Castle, near the end.

Comment: Apparently that guy had a typo in his guide. One of the stars labeled "Tomb Dungeon" was actually the rock dungeon. But I fixed it!